# htlatex outputs extra word not in document when using \columnbreak with multicols

Tags: tex4ht

texlive 2014, Linux. MWE

```
\documentclass{article}%
\usepackage{lipsum,multicol}
\begin{document}  
\begin{multicols}{2}

\section*{Introduction}
This is introduction

\columnbreak
\section*{my section}
This is my section

\end{multicols}
\end{document}
```

Here is the PDF and the HTML output side by side. Notice htlatex output has an extra word `auto` in the output.

[image: Mathematica graphics]

This can only be a bug? removing `\columnbreak` removes the word `auto` from the HTML page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know that this issue is old, but I've found it just today. I've tried to compile the MWE and it works without problems, so it seems that it was fixed in the meantime:

[image]